# Folder.MoveTo will reset the main folder fields. can i preserve them

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, move-to

I am working on a remote event receiver inside SharePoint online, and i have a code to move a folder to another library. now the source and destination libraries have the same content type and each library contain 5 managed metadata columns. now i want to move FolderA from lib1 to lib2, so i try the follow:-

```
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lib1/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
folder.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lib2/" );
```

But this will raise an error that it `can not rename FolderA to lib2, folder already exists`, so seems i need to add the FolderA name inside the destination path, so i tried the following:-

```
 Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lib1/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
 folder.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lib2/"+ currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
```

this has moved the folder, but the main folder FolderA will lost its managed metadata values, while the MoveTo has preserve the managed metadata for the sub-folders and files. can anyone advice if i can force the MoveTo to preserve the managed metadata for the main folder as well?

Thanks